# Вложенные массивы в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, unity3d-editor

В Unity в инспекторе не отображаются вложенные массивы или я что то не так делаю? Мне необходимо вывести массив массивов в инспектор для заполнения.

У меня есть массив классов, вернее структур, в которых первое поле это имя свойства оружия, второе и третье это мин-макс значения, которые данное свойство может принять рандомно при генерации.

Однако у оружия есть степени легендарности и для каждой степени легендарности эти мин макс значения для свойства должны быть свои. Соответственно я решил создать массив этих массивов классов. Может быть есть какое либо другое решение или есть способ отобразить вложенные массивы в инспекторе?

Код самой структуры:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

    public enum PropertyName
{

    phisicalDamageBonus,
    phisicalDamageBonusPercents,
    atackSpeedBonusPercents,
    earthDamageBonus,
    earthDamageBonusPercents,
    fireDamageBonus,
    fireDamageBonusPercents,
    airDamageBonus,
    airDamageBonusPercents,
    waterDamageBonus,
    waterDamageBonusPercents,
    lifeStealBonus,
    lifeStealBonusPercents,
    manaStealBonus,
    manaStealBonusPercents
}
[System.Serializable]
public struct Property{

    public PropertyName name;
    public int minValue;
    public int maxValue;

    public int Generate()
    {
        return Random.Range(minValue, maxValue);
    }

}
```

Comment: Как крайний случай, есть ещё вариант Custom Editor, там вы можете сделать любой редактор вашего monobehaviour (или его отдельных частей) в инспекторе

Comment: Спасибо, в этом направлении тоже покопаюсь, рано или поздно все же придется браться за эту тему)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здарвствуйте! Могу предложить такой вариант массива в массиве. Может быть выглядит не очень, но более менее можно будет сориентироваться в инспекторе.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class SubList {
    public string name; // дополнительное поле, чтобы в инсекторе отобразить имя массива для удобства
    public List<Property> list = new List<Property>();
}

// использование
public List<SubList> myArray = new List<SubList>();
```

В инспекторе примерно отобразится так:

[image: котятки]

Надеюсь вам поможет, или натолкнет на мысль какую.

Comment: Да, спасибо, думаю так и сделаю, как то даже не подумал)